# Laravel naming convention with similar Model names

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is a very basic question but trying to wrap my head around the preferred naming conventions for models/tables with similar names.

A model 'Task' can have many 'Comments' so the tables would be
- tasks
- comments (with a foreign key for task_id)

However, I have another model 'Post' which will also need a 'Comments' which is of course separate from the Comments for Tasks

In this scenario, does one generally go with
- Task & TaskComment (model) / tasks & task_comments (database table)
- Post & PostComment (model) / posts & post_comments (database table)

or some other convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use polymorphic relations you can even make a Comments has its own comments (like a reply system).

In the model you want to have comments you need to add a method like this:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

Then in your Comment model, you just add

```
public function commentable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Notice how important it is that your method name in Comment matches with the second parameter passed to the morpMany() function.**

Last but not least, the model in which you morph to needs to have special fields in its schema:

You must place them at the end of the traditional schema structure:

```
// Your comment dedicated schema
$table->integer('commentable_id');
$table->string('commentable_type');
```

I really don't know if it is important but notice how the field prefix matches with the method name in which we are morphing.

Comment: thanks for the answer - that made perfect sense and I was able to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

What you want for this is polymorphism.

Follow the example on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations . It's really close to what you are trying to do, so hopefully it will be enough. If you get stuck let me know and i'll help you along